# postgresql search in time ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

So here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a number of events, each event represents a datetime range (like 07.03.2014 06:00 - 07.03.2014 08:00)
event is associated (one-to-many) to `hall_schedule`.

Then I want to search for all `hall_schedule's` that don't have events that cover some specific time range, for example:

"I want all hall_schedules where hall events don't cover the 07.03.2014 06:00 - 07.03.2014 08:00 range"

So the question is, in order to get the best performance, how do I design this? What is the best way to store events and later do the described search?

I'd be glad to use something specific to postgresql (9.3), whatever would give the best performance

Comment: *Cover* is a fuzzy word here. Edit your question, and include CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for some sample data.

Comment: See [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589) and [2 B-tree indices OR 1 GiST index on tsrange — which will perform better?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59074) on dba.SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` for `hall_schedule`'s `start` and `end` time points
2. use [`tstzrange`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html) to detect [overlappings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE), like:

   ```
   SELECT *
     FROM "hall_schedule"
    WHERE NOT (tstzrange("start", "end", '[]') &&
               tstzrange(:input_start, :input_end, '[]'))
   ```

Notes:

- you could store the whole range in a `tstzrange` column within the `hall_schedule` table, if you want, but it's harder to edit from the application (you must supply its text representation everywhere)
- this way, you can actually create [`EXCLUDE` constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE) too, to prevent events in `hall_schedule` to overlap each other, if you want.

Update:

Additionally, to speed up your queries, you can add the following index too:

```
CREATE INDEX "hall_schedule_range_idx"
          ON "hall_schedule"
       USING gist ((tstzrange("start", "end", '[]')));
```